# On bootstrap navbar, dropdown tab works properly, but prevents other main menu tab links work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I saw many similar questions, and none of the answers worked for me. 
My bootstrap navbar was working fine, until I added submenu for one of the tabs, and set it as a dropdown list. But after this, the other tabs on the main menu stopped working. Here is part of my html head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and this is my navbar:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="resume" data-toggle="tab">Resume</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="java" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="secondLayer"><a class="font" href="java">Java</a></li>
            <li class="secondLayer"><a href="cSharp">C-sharp</a></li>
            <li class="secondLayer"><a href="uml">UML</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contactMe" data-toggle="tab">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutMe" data-toggle="tab">About Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Could anybody please help me on this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "stopped working"? The tabs appear to still go active when I click on them.

Comment: When I click on the menu tabs like Resume, they don't do anything. There are hrefs, and they are supposed to work as links

Comment: I made a fiddle out of your code, and the tabs seem to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/audqL0g7/. Is this the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: The tabs get active and it seems that they are selected when you click on them, but the link doesn't actually work. It means there is no navigation

Comment: When I remove the jquery script from html head, the links are back, but the dropdown doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the tabs to act like links, just remove `data-toggle="tab"` from everything. Bootstrap has some JS plugged in so that your tabs activate and are pretty for usual navigation, but if you just want them to be links and only want the CSS, there's no need to have that functionality attached.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7n6vpmb/).

Comment: Thsnk you Karin. The answer was great. Now I can finally get some sleep ;)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how this worked **before you added the dropdown**. The issue is that all of your tags are like `href="index"` and are missing the `#` to indicate that they are ids. Change them all to like this `href="#index"`. See the below example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#index">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#resume" data-toggle="tab">Resume</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="java" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li class="secondLayer"><a class="font" href="java">Java</a></li>
      <li class="secondLayer"><a href="cSharp">C-sharp</a></li>
      <li class="secondLayer"><a href="uml">UML</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contactMe" data-toggle="tab">Contact Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#aboutMe" data-toggle="tab">About Me</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane active" id="index">index</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="resume">resume</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="contactMe">contactMe</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="aboutMe">aboutMe</div>
</div>
```

**Note** if you actually want these to be *links* and not tabs, you are using the wrong elements, get rid of all the references to tabs and toggle and use urls in your  hrefs like `href="index.html"`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but we only add # when we want to point to a specific id within the page. ids like "index" are actually index.html, but in order to make the urls look nicer and more professional, we remove .html and add a .htaccess file to the root of the app, to resolve the urls

Comment: @Bahman Then try removing the `data-toggle="tab"` from each of them. Im not sure if that is the issue, but  `data-toggle="tab"` has a specific meaning in bootstrap (ie the example I showed above) and this is NOT what you are using these elements for .